# JQuery .load() unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a `div parent` where every `child div` is a list of items populated dynamically from the server. Each item has a checkbox next to it, which when checked sends that item to the bottom of the list in `parent div`.

I have a ajax request that sends back to the server the checkbox status to update the database record, after this `ajax` call I then try to use the `.load()` method to repopulate the `div parent` with each `child div`to also include the checked item to be at the end of the list.

I try this:

```
$('#showTasks').load('/wp #showTasks', function(){
    loadTasks();    
});
```

Where `#showTasks` is the parent div and `loadTasks()` gets the server data and creates and appends each child div to the parent and appends checked items to the end of the `div`.

This however doesn't send the checked item to the bottom and I have to refresh manually to see this particular div element appended last on the list.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can put your piece of code in the $(document) as shown below

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#showTasks").load();
  loadTasks();
});
```